# Crop background image after positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the following code that allows the user to choose a picture to upload:

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('filePhoto');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        $('.coverPicture').css('background-image', 'url(' + event.target.result + ')');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

The picture that the user chooses are attached as a background to my `coverPicture` div. The user can then position the background image by dragging it around in the div.

When the user is finished positioning the background image, I want to crop the image as it appears in the div. How can I do this with JavaScript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are couple of really good javascript libraries you can consider

Cropper
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Darkroom
https://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/

Suggested by Bryan (image crop with background images)
http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit

Comment: The library above only covers how to crop Images? Im using a background-image.

Comment: Yeah thats a good library as well, let me update my answer to add that. Thanks

Comment: http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/ - how I can download original size image using this plugin.